# Angularjs showing tab content from an array

Tags: angularjs, tabs, controllers

I am building my first Angular SPA. In a form I have three tabs, and want a tab to show only its contents and only when selected. The tab contents are in an array in the controller. 
I have been playing around with different $scope configurations all evening, but can only make nothing, or the content of all 3 tabs appear at once. I can't isolate the content of one tab from the array in the view. I feel like I must be misunderstanding the $scope, but can't seem to find any documentation that fits the situation. Perhaps its completely the wrong way to go about it. In short, I would greatly appreciate any help or advice from you angular gurus out there :)

Thanks so much!! Here's the code:

I am keeping the tab content and functions as an array in the controller like this:

```
$scope.tabs = [
    {
        title: 'Free',
        description: 'free',
        price: 'free',
        elem: 'free'
    },{
        title: 'Basic',
        description: 'basic',
        price: '9.97',
        elem: 'basic'
    },{
        title: 'Unlimited',
        description: 'Every service',
        price: '19',
        elem: 'unlimited'
    }
];

$scope.currentTab = 'free';

$scope.onClickTab = function (tab) {
    $scope.currentTab = tab.elem;
    $('.tab-content').hide();
    $('#'+tab.url).show();
}

$scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
    return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
}
```

I use ng-repeat to create the selection buttons:

```
<li class="tab-option" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" 
ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(tab.elem)}" 
ng-click="onClickTab(tab)">{{tab.elem}}
</li>
```

Below this, I want to display the price etc.. of the tab selected in a separate box. I see that {{tab.elem}} selects the correct part of the array, so I thought that {{tab.price}} would do the same.
But, when I use {{tab.price}} or any other {{tab.}} , like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <p>{{tab.description}}</p>
    <p>{{tab.price}}</p>
</div>
```

I get nothing.

Thanks again for any help, advice or thoughts! 
-Berkeley

Answer (score 0):

The same functionality can be achieved in a different way
by the way we define onClickTab function.
Instead of storing $scope.currentTab as 'free' make it a reference to current tab
viz. $scope.currentTab=tab;
And then you can simply avoid the jquery selectors inside the function as it is not a good practise to do so. 
In the content div where you need to show the price description use currentTab instead of tab.
Summarizing

```
<li class="tab-option" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" 
ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(tab)}" 
ng-click="onClickTab(tab)">{{tab.elem}}
</li>
```

Controller logic

```
//default one
$scope.currentTab=$scope.tabs[0];


$scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
 return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
}    

$scope.onClickTab = function (tab) {
 $scope.currentTab = tab.elem;  
}
```

Content to be displayed by current tab

```
<div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<p>{{currentTab.description}}</p>
<p>{{currentTab.price}}</p>
</div>
```

Always avoid hiding or showing elements in controller, as far as dom manipulations
are concerned make them using a directive. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still playing with it to make it work like I want it to, but your advice has gotten me a lot closer.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working!

The controller:

```
$scope.currentTab = $scope.tabs[0];

$scope.onClickTab = function (tab) {
    $scope.currentTab = tab;
}
```

the view:

```
 <div class="description">
    <p class="text-center">{{currentTab.description}}</p>
    <p class="text-center">{{currentTab.price}}</p>
 </div>
```

This is all the code I needed. I used Naveen's advice of using the tab[order] to call it initially, but was struggling still with getting the comments to show up with the correct information only when selected.

I had been using $scope.currentTab = tab.elem; this doesn't work because it is trying to be too specific. By changing it to simply "tab" angular knew to treat all the tab's contents as the new $scope.currentTab so that when I call {{currentTab.description}} I get the correct response.

And with that I will close this question. Thanks so much!